# Writing files with a pool of workers

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x

I have to write some files that are quite big, I'd like to do this in a separate thread (use processor and HDD at the same time) and I'd like to use a pool of workers of size 4 (because there are other operations besides writing, I guesstimate 4 is enough to use the HDD properly without clogging it).

This is the code I have (it does nothing):

```
import os, os.path, multiprocessing

def asyncFileMake(e):
    with open('files/file%d.txt'%e, 'w') as f:
        print(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(os.getcwd())))
        f.write("hi")

def writefile(e, pool):
    pool.apply_async(asyncFileMake, [e])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    if not os.path.exists('files'):
        os.makedirs('files')
    with multiprocessing.Pool(processes=4) as pool:
        for e in range(10):
          writefile(e, pool)
```

Comment: What might the question be?

Comment: He says the code does nothing. Probably the question is why it does nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a version which is inspired by your original code snippet. I think the most significant change is the way the function is passed to the pool (`map` instead of `apply_async`, more on that later):

```
import os
import multiprocessing

def create_file(e):
    with open('files/file%d.txt'%e, 'w') as f:
        print f.name
        f.write("hi")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if not os.path.exists('files'):
            os.makedirs('files')
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=4)
    pool.map(create_file, range(10))
```

The problem with your original implementation is, that `pool.apply_async` returns a `AsyncResult` on which you need to call `get` so that the actual execution gets triggered. I suggest you take another close look at the [documentation of multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html). Especially [this part about pool workers](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#using-a-pool-of-workers). Hope that helps.

Comment: Your should probably add some text explaining what changes you made and why

Comment: I added some explanations. Tell me if you feel like something is missing.

Comment: I had to refactor a bit of the code because it wasn't ready to be used as a map, but now it works like a charm, thank you. Fortunately it's not a warm day because I'm gonna rock this processor...